# Hadith about a man who wanted to enter jannah with only his deeds

Tags: hadith, source-identification

There is a Hadith that talks about that - A man has many good deeds but Allah told the angel to take him to jannah with his mercy but the man wanted to enter jannah with his good deeds instead of Allah's mercy. So Allah asked him for his eyesight.

Can anyone provide the reference for this Hadith?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recorded in [Shu'ab al-Eemaan 4300](https://shamela.ws/book/10660/4738) , [Mustadrak al-Hakim 7637](https://shamela.ws/book/2266/8484) etc. A similar lesson but not this story may also be found in the hadith found in [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6467) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/52/65-76).

**Ref:**

- https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/108221/ (Arabic)
- https://hadithanswers.com/a-narration-on-entering-jannah-through-the-mercy-of-allah-taala/ (English)

Answer (score 1):

Asalamualikum,

This hadith is obtained from ''Tambihul Ghafilun'' by Sheikh Abul Laith Samarkandi. This book contains many authentic as well as weak and fabricated narrations.

Jazakallah khair.